# Windows 10 MemoryDiagnostics result

Tags: windows, memory, memtest, bluescreenview

my computer got a bluescreeen (KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED), so i started the memory diagnostic tool.
I cant get it what this result means. Is the test passed without errors/problems or are they errors ?

Thank you very much...

```
Protokollname: System
Quelle:        Microsoft-Windows-MemoryDiagnostics-Schedule
Datum:         08. Mai. 2021 17:01:42
Ereignis-ID:   1001
Aufgabenkategorie:Keine
Ebene:         Informationen
Schlüsselwörter:
Benutzer:      ASUS-G17\juliu
Computer:      ASUS-G17
Beschreibung:
Von der Windows-Speicherdiagnose wurde die sofortige Ausführung des Arbeitsspeichertests für den Computer geplant.
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-MemoryDiagnostics-Schedule" Guid="{73e9c9de-a148-41f7-b1db-4da051fdc327}" />
    <EventID>1001</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-08T15:01:42.2915437Z" />
    <EventRecordID>15827</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="19008" ThreadID="19180" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>ASUS-G17</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3341167928-4050467313-4173444180-1001" />
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <Schedule xmlns="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2005/08/Windows/Memory/Diagnostic/Schedule/Events">
      <LaunchType>Manual</LaunchType>
      <ScheduleType>Immediate</ScheduleType>
    </Schedule>
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has said that this sort of error is one where you would need to re-install Windows because a Windows component has failed to function. That specific component being either corrupt files or corrupt drivers. Reinstalling Windows would be a good idea to get your computer back on its feet.

Some clarification for you: `Ereignis-ID: 1001` is a simple event log claiming the system rebooted due to an error. This event is thrown out after *every* blue-screen a computer can get. Based on the info about the exception, I would still reinstall Windows.

Comment: Specifically, "something" in the kernel threw an exception.. (bad code) and no code was there to deal with it.  it was probably a device driver (as you point out) and probably not a component of windows itself.. but your answer is a good one. +1 :)

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. My windows installation is just 1 month old. Shit happens. I think im going to reinstall windows right now.

Comment: Good idea. Glad I could help :)